# Target multiple selectors in JS only

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to implement a click event on my site without jQuery.

I want to target multiple selectors.

In jQuery this can be done by simply comma seperating the items as shown below.

```
jQuery(document).on('click', '#test1, #test2', function (event) {
    alert($(this).text());
});
```

How can this easily be done in plain javascript?

I have tried the below which works but it seems like there should be a simpler way especially if I want more than an alert to occur on click?  I want to target more than one specific selector not all divs for example

```
var test1 = document.getElementById('test1');
var test2 = document.getElementById('test2');

if (test1.addEventListener || test2.addEventListener) {
    test1.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
        alert(this.innerHTML);
    });
    test2.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
        alert(this.innerHTML);
    });

    /* this only works when you click on test2
    (test1,test2).addEventListener('click', function(event) {
        alert(this.innerHTML);
    });
    */
    /* this only works when you click on test2
    (test1.addEventListener),(test2.addEventListener)('click', function(event) {
        alert(this.innerHTML);
    });        
    */
}
```

```js
    var test1 = document.getElementById('test1');
    var test2 = document.getElementById('test2');
    if (test1.addEventListener || test2.addEventListener) {
        test1.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
            alert(this.innerHTML);
        });
        test2.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
            alert(this.innerHTML);
        });
    }
```

```html
<div id="test1">test1</div>
<div id="test2">test2</div>
```

Is there a way to comma seperate the selectors, or setup all selctors before running the code like you can with jQuery?

Comment: why don't you use jQuery?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This would be basically the equivalent code minus all the browser checking:

```js
document.body.addEventListener("click", function(e) {  //bind event to the document
   var targ = e.target;  //get what was clicked on
   var id = targ.id;  //grab the id
   if (["test1","test2"].indexOf(id)!==-1){ //see if it is one of the ids
       alert(targ.textContent);    //show the text
   }
}, false);
```

```html
<div id="test1">test 1</div>
<div id="test2">test 2</div>
<div id="test3">test 3</div>
```

Comment: *addEventListener*, *e.target* and *textContent* all fail in IE 8. :-(

Comment: @RobG—the OP doesn't ask for that.

Comment: The OP shouldn't have to specify support for a browser that rates [*around 20%*](http://www.netmarketshare.com) of the desktop user share.

Comment: @RobG I see, but that percentage doesn't belong to IE8!

Comment: @Vohuman—for some reason I was shown the values for September 2013. I have no idea why. The value for November 2014 is 15.11%, still a significant value.

Answer (score 8):

You can use *querySelectorAll*:

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('#test1, #test2');
for (var i=0, iLen=elements.length; i<iLen; i++) {
  // add listeners to elements[i];
}
```

Or if you want to mix host objects with native methods (not a good idea but…):

```
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('#test1, #test2'), function(el) {
  // attach listener to el
});
```

But event delegation may be a better idea than attaching the same listener to multiple elements.

Comment: @epascarello—the OP doesn't ask for that.

Comment: Why not `for...in`?

Comment: @Alex78191— for..in iterates over all properties, including those on the \[\[Prototype\]\] chain, not just indexed properties. There is a [*NodeList.forEach* method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach), however in 2014 it wasn't well supported.

Answer (score 1):

Bind a handler to the parent and use event delegation. http://javascript.info/tutorial/event-delegation

Answer (score 1):

Build an array of selectors then iterate through it adding the event listeners. Also put your alert or whatever action you want into a function. **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/wd5exzLd/)**

```
var selectors = new Array("test1", "test2");

for(var i=0; i < selectors.length; i++) {
    var temp = document.getElementById(selectors[i]);
    temp.addEventListener('click', function() {
        clickaction(this.innerHTML);
    });
}

function clickaction(content) {
    alert(content);
}
```

Comment: @vp_arth, the OP asks for a more concise, manageable way of handing the situation... Yes this method includes multiple event listeners, but it has the performance advantage of not handling events for every click on every page element (or anywhere in the body). A different approach to solve the problem. Simply put, it's a DRY solution that lets the OP manage the list of selectors in a single array variable.

Comment: Hm, I read: 'Is there a way to comma seperate the selectors, or setup all selctors before running the code like you can with jQuery?'

Comment: You have not `event delegation`. If one of element will replaced - listener will be lost.

Comment: Just that elements listener is lost... The others remain intact as they are seperate listeners.

Comment: Aha, half-page doesn't work at all - but other half still works!!

Answer (score 0):

Event delegation with indexOf polyfill if necessary.

```js
var arrIDsToWatch = ["test1", "test2", "test5"];

// indexOf Polyfill from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf#Compatibility
if (!Array.prototype.indexOf) {
  Array.prototype.indexOf = function(searchElement, fromIndex) {
    var k;
    if (this == null) {
      throw new TypeError('"this" is null or not defined');
    }
    var O = Object(this);
    var len = O.length >>> 0;
    if (len === 0) {
      return -1;
    }
    var n = +fromIndex || 0;
    if (Math.abs(n) === Infinity) {
      n = 0;
    }

    if (n >= len) {
      return -1;
    }
    k = Math.max(n >= 0 ? n : len - Math.abs(n), 0);

    while (k < len) {
      if (k in O && O[k] === searchElement) {
        return k;
      }
      k++;
    }
    return -1;
  };
}


document.getElementById('parent').onclick = function(e) {
  e = e || event
  var target = e.target || e.srcElement
  var targetID = target.id;
  if (arrIDsToWatch.indexOf(targetID) > -1) {
    alert(target.innerHTML);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="test1">test1</div>
  <div id="test2">test2</div>
  <div id="test3">test3</div>
  <div id="test4">test4</div>
  <div id="test5">test5</div>
</div>
```